# Would if be correct/worthwhile to put __attribute__((const)) on a function that DOES access global memory is also entirely a function of the input?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, compiler-optimization

The use case is as follow:

I have a map which will have some key/values inserted into it.

The program will query this map but after the first query I can guarantee that the map will not be modified at all.

Would it be correct to put a **attribute**((const)) on my query method because the result of query is entirely a function of the input?

If this would not break things could this yield any performance benefit with A) keys whose values are known at compile time and B) keys whose values are NOT known at compile time?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Formally, this is not correct. A compiler doing whole-program optimization can lift the query calls all the way to the top of `main`. I actually encountered something similar with `__attribute__((__const__))` on `__errno_location()`, where the compiler lifted computation of `errno`'s address (since it was later used unconditionally) before libc/dynamic-linker startup code, and thus before thread-local-storage was setup. (I later solved this by using hard barriers to separate stages of initialization in ways that don't admit lifting from one to another, but this kind of solution is really only appropriate for systems-level programming, not for an application.)

In terms of whether you can get away with it, maybe. If you know you won't be using LTO or whole-program compilation, or if you can put some sort of volatile-address indirect-call barrier between the code that performs the queries and the code that makes the table, it might end up being okay in practice. Another option you might consider is whether you can make the table statically initialized, so that the lookup call is valid anytime.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't expect the keys to be known at compile time so static is not an option. The barrier approach sounds intriguing (even if just to learn). Could you by any chance point me in the direction of a resource on the subject? Without any keywords I am having trouble finding anything on Google. Thank you!

Comment: Something like `volatile void (*funcptr)(...) = do_work;` where `do_work` is the function that does everything involving the lookups, and is only ever called via `funcptr`, so that the compiler is forced to generate a load of the function address and indirect call rather than being able to make assumptions about (and lift from) the code it's calling.

Comment: A better solution however might be use of the `pure` attribute instead of `const`. This represents that its result can depend on the table object (or any other objects that are globally visible or whose addresses have leaked past what the compiler can see) and thus will not enable caching of results when the compiler can't prove that such data hasn't changed, but depending on your usage the caching `pure` allows may be sufficient, and it's a lot less error-prone than lying to the compiler.

Comment: Does the ```volatile void (*funcptr)(...) = do_work;``` add overhead to the calls? Also how would the the compiler cache the values if it doesnt know which function is being called? But I agree I could probably make the pure idea work if im careful about the aliasing. Thanks!

Comment: @Noah: Yes. If you take this path you wouldn't do it around each small operation but around the "whole thing" that's whatever your program does after building the table. But it's really an ugly hack and I'd avoid doing it unless you measure that redundant calls are the bottleneck.